# What type of distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What is the best way to tell what kind of probability distribution this is?

[image]

I'm new to statistics and I'm kind of familiar with normal, binomial and Poisson distributions, but this one looks very random! Any tips?

Comment: What's the context? What are you trying to achieve/understand? It's just the distribution you present. Probably resulting from some sampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a probability distribution it looks pretty random, but it does quite look like the normalization of a histogram of samples from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, i.e. each sample is a random number between 0 and 1, all with equal probability.
In your histogram, it looks like the values are binned in slightly over 100 bins, and the total number of samples is harder to see, but it looks like there are around 5000 to 10000 of them.

If we consider just a single bin as an independent random variable, into which a uniform random number falls with probability $p = 0.01$, then the distribution of the count inside each bin is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $B(10000, 0.01)$ with [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) $\mathcal N(100, 99)$, i.e. a  normal distribution with standard deviation $\sqrt{99}\approx 10$.

Our 100 bins give us 100 samples from this distribution (they are not really independent, but since there are so many, we can pretend they are). Around $1/6$ should be above $1\sigma$ from the mean, hence above 1.1 if the number of samples was 10000 indeed, and $1/6$ below 0.9. I count around 16 values above, and 20 below, close enough to the expected $100/6 = 16\frac23$, so it looks quite a bit like a sampling of around 10000 elements (maybe a somewhat less) from a uniform distribution.

Finally, a visual verification: if I generate 10000 random uniform samples from $[0,1]$ and I put them in a histogram with 100 bins, it looks like this:

[image: histogram of 10000 uniform samples]

pretty similar to yours (even the same software was probably used). The code used was

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(np.random.random(10000), bins=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow! It was indeed 10000 points! Thank you so much for your answer sir!:)